# Python multiprocessing - result of Pool.map is None

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am struggling in getting my multiprocessing up and running. Below there is an example of my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import ast
import numpy as np
import itertools
import glob
from multiprocessing import Pool as ProcessPool

def network_inference(year)   
   # some code that generate a net and a df_complete dataframe
   res = pd.Series()
   res['YEAR'] = year
   res['NODES'] = net.number_of_nodes()
   res['EDGES'] = net.number_of_edges()

   return (res, df_complete['VENUE_CLASS'].value_counts())


if __name__=='__main__':
    years = [x.replace('\\','/').replace('data_of_interest.csv','') for x in glob.glob('data/raw/*/data_of_interest.csv')][:10]
    pool = ProcessPool(50) 
    results = pool.map_async(network_inference, years)
    pool.close() 
    pool.join()

    results.wait()

    l = results.get()

    structure = pd.DataFrame()
    for s1,s2 in l:
        structure = structure.append(s1.append(s2), ignore_index=True)

    structure.to_csv('data/structure_data_features.csv', index = False)
```

As you can see is pretty simple, a map function over a list of files. Every process returns a tuple. So the problem happens when I call `result.get()`. When the code is running, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/AD-HOME/------/Desktop/dblp/network_inference.py", line 132, in <module>
    for s1,s2 in l:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

However, if later after the error I ask the result (`results.get()`) in the Ipython terminal (I am using Spyder), I got the correct output. I wanted to post a complete `mwe`, however, I am not able to reproduce this error with a simpler code and I cannot post the original one.

I am looking for ideas to fix this problem, I understand that when calling `map` I need to wait for it to compute everything (and I believe I am doing that with `join()` and then with `results.wait()`).

Comment: Just to clarify, what are you using for `ProcessPool`?

Comment: I added the import section. @MyNameIsCaleb

Comment: If you're going to instantly wait on the pool, can't you just use blocking `pool.map` instead? I suspect that could fix the problem.

Comment: I would use a context using with like `with Pool(processes=4) as pool:` and then you can drop your close and join methods. I am guessing your results are potentially getting dropped before you access them. The docs generally show retrieving results prior to joining. In Spyder, your results are getting cached meaning you may be able to access them from when they existed. If that is all, I'll add it as a real answer.

Comment: Also the `.get()` method waits until the results are ready anyway, so you should be able to use just that.

Comment: I tried using `pool.map`, but it does not work. @AndrasDeak

Comment: When you say "it does not work" do you mean "it gives me None and thus the same error", or something else?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It returns None, the same error that I mentioned in the question. @AndrasDeak

Comment: The same error even using the context method proposed by @MyNameIsCaleb. I really do not know what is going on.

Comment: Can you put them in the context, not use join/close/wait, and then print `l` right after `l = results.get()`

Comment: Since you're using spyder there's a high chance your system is haunted. Have you tried restarting the IDE once or twice? That can do wonders with spyder.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I have already tried that, even running outside Spyder.

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb I rebooted my system and now the context method is working, however, I really do not understand why `close` and `join` are not working here. Returning value in the way I am returning them is bad practice in Python?

Comment: Because when you close and join, the results are getting deleted before you access them is what I suspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend managing context using `with`:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    years = [x.replace('\\','/').replace('data_of_interest.csv','') for x in glob.glob('data/raw/*/data_of_interest.csv')][:10]
    with ProcessPool(50) as pool:
        results = pool.map_async(network_inference, years)
        l = results.get()

        structure = pd.DataFrame()
        for s1,s2 in l:
            structure = structure.append(s1.append(s2), ignore_index=True)

        structure.to_csv('data/structure_data_features.csv', index = False)
```

You can drop `close` and `join` using this method, and then you need to access your results and do something with them before leaving the context of the `ProcessPool`.  When you `close` and `join`, your results are getting removed before you access them.

You also don't need `wait` here since you are using `.get()` immediately after which will already wait for your results.